# ASP.net MVC 5 Loading another view and stopping the current view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

**New to MVC** so here is my question.

I am wanting to load another view if the user falls into a category. As an example:

```
namespace toolSwitchboard.Controllers
{
    public class SwitchboardController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Switchboard
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page for Switchboard.";
            ViewData["theYear"] = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

            getMainData();

            return View();
        }

    public ActionResult getMainData()
    {            
        if (UnboundNewClass == "NEW")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AddPresenter"); //Latest try
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Admin = false;
            ViewBag.AddP = false;
            ViewBag.MyClasses = true;
            ViewBag.Change = true;
            ViewBag.New = false;
            ViewBag.BTT = false;
            ViewBag.Eval = false;
            ViewBag.cup = false;
            ViewBag.SCHEDULE = false;
            ViewBag.Travel = false;

            return View();
        }
    }
    }
}
```

I'm calling this code inside the **public class SwitchboardController : Controller**.

Though doing the above does not seem to load the **AddPresenter** view and *still* loads the current View (which is called **Switchboard**). And of course it gets errors when loading the **Switchboard** view since I have some RAZOR code on the Index.cshtml page that it doesn't have any data for.

I've tried:

```
return View("~/Views/AddPresenter/Index.cshtml");
return View("AddPresenter", "AddPresenter");
return View("../AddPresenter/Index", "AddPresenter");
return View("~/AddPresenter/Index", "AddPresenter");
return View("~/AddPresenter/Index");
return RedirectToAction("AddPresenter", "AddPresenter", null);
return RedirectToAction("Index", "AddPresenter");
```

And none seem to work. They just load up the **Switchboard** Index.cshtml page instead of the needed **AddPresenter** Index.cshtml page.

This is my Switchboard View where it has the error:

```
//More code above....
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="yellowArea">
        <p class="boxStyle">Presentation:</p>
        <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom1" id="NewT">TRAVEL</Button>
        <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom2" id="NewE">External</Button>
        <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom3" id="Credits">Credits</Button>

        @if (ViewBag.BTT)
        {
            <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-large btnCustom4" id="BTT">BTT</Button>
        }
    </div>
    <div id="clearArea1">
    //More code below....
```

The error is on the **ViewBag.BTT** line because I only set those if they are only going to view the **Switchboard View** and not the **AddPresenter View**.

What kinds of things can I do in order to correct this the way I need to load the views?

Comment: you sure presenter == "NEW" is true?

Comment: @Steve yes sir. Had a break there and it does, indeed, follow that if path.

Comment: try return View("~/Views/AddPresenter/Index"). though I think redirect should work

Comment: Unclear what your asking. If the value of `presenter`is `"NEW"` you will be redirected (assuming your not using ajax), other wise you return the current view. But your not returning a model in the `return View()` statement which may generate errors if your referencing its properties

Comment: @Steve Still goes to the current Index page.

Comment: And your redirect goes to the `AddPresenter()` method of `AddPresenterController` (not to an `Index` view)

Comment: return RedirectToAction("AddPresenter", "AddPresenter", null); would redirect you to controller named "AddPresenterController" and the public method "AddPresenter()".

It might be handy to give us a little more scope of your project. Other controllers, view hierarchy, etc.

Comment: Show us the entire Controller.

Comment: return RedirectToAction("Index", "AddPresenter");

You want to redirect to action method of "AddPresenter" controller then you will write as above

Comment: @Dobbins Added to the OP.

Comment: @JesseMoreland Added to the OP.

Comment: @Khalid I just tried that (you can see it in my OP update) and it still loads up the Switchboard view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finally got it fixed. It was all caused by the **return View();** that was in the **Switchboard ActionResult Index()** method.

Changing that code to this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page for Switchboard.";
    ViewData["theYear"] = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    return getMainData();
}
```

Instead of this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page for Switchboard.";
    ViewData["theYear"] = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    getMainData();

    return View();
}
```

Did allow me to load up the **AddPresenter** View without the Switchboard View being loaded still and causing errors.

Using **return RedirectToAction("Index", "AddPresenter");** worked out of all the ones I had tried:

```
    if (UnboundNewClass == "NEW")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "AddPresenter");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Admin = false;
        ViewBag.AddP = false;
        ViewBag.MyClasses = true;
        ViewBag.Change = true;
        ViewBag.New = false;
        ViewBag.BTT = false;
        ViewBag.Eval = false;
        ViewBag.cup = false;
        ViewBag.SCHEDULE = false;
        ViewBag.Travel = false;

        return View();
    }
```

Thanks to all who provided help and incite! :o)

Answer (score 1):

I you want to load an other `view` you just pass the name of the view.

e.g.:

```
if (presenter == "NEW")
{
    return View("AddPresenter");
} else 
{
    return View();
}
```

If presenter == "NEW", ASP.NET will search in "Views\NameOfTheController".
If the given viewname does not exsists, the search will continue in "Views\Shared".

If presenter != "NEW", ASP.Net will follow the same rules to find the view. The standard viewname is the `ActionName` (or `Method` in the controller)

If you want to redirect to an other controller, use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.String%29) overload of `RedirectToAction`:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index","NameOfTheController");
```

This will bring you right to `/NameOfTheController/Index`.
In your case:

```
Return RedirectToAction("Index","AddPresenter");
```

Comment: That seems to produce the same error (And loading of the Switchboard View still).

Answer (score 1):

This is your main controller, your switchboard:

```
namespace toolSwitchboard.Controllers
{
    public class SwitchboardController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Switchboard
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page for Switchboard.";
            ViewData["theYear"] = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

            getMainData();

            return View();
        }

    public ActionResult getMainData()
    {            
        if (UnboundNewClass == "NEW")
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "AddPresenter"); //Will Redirect you to AddPresenterController.Index()
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.Admin = false;
            ViewBag.AddP = false;
            ViewBag.MyClasses = true;
            ViewBag.Change = true;
            ViewBag.New = false;
            ViewBag.BTT = false;
            ViewBag.Eval = false;
            ViewBag.cup = false;
            ViewBag.SCHEDULE = false;
            ViewBag.Travel = false;

            return View();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Your AddPresenter Class:

```
public class AddPresenterController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(); // Potentially put view name here as parameter
    }
}
```

Some things I want you to check for is that:

1) You have a folder inside of your Views folder named AddPresenter. In order for a controller to access a view, it has to be in their own folder(Views->ControllerName) or in the shared folder under views.

2) Inside of that Views->AddPresenter folder, you have a view named Index, If its not you need to pass the viewname into the Index Method of AddPresenters return.

3) Your routes(AppStart->RouteConfig) have the default routes.